# Imaginary number conversion property

Tags: calculus

So provided that $ab$ is extremely small, is there anyway to show that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-ab}}=1 + i\frac{ab}{2}$$

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-iab}}$?

Comment: I suggest that (1) edit your Q as there is a major typo. (2), Provide some background or show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

For small real $x$, by Taylor

$$\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}\approx1+\frac x2.$$

Your claim cannot hold.

---

Note that

$$(1-x)\left(1+\frac x2\right)^2=1-x^2\frac{x+3}4\approx 1-x^2,$$

which gives you an idea of the accuracy of the approximation.